# Set of final states of initial value problem of an ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let $g\in C([0,1]\times\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$ be locally Lipschitz in the second argument and bounded, and consider the IVP
$$\dot{x}(t) = g(t,x(t)),\, t\in [0,1],\quad x(0) = x_0 \tag*{$(\star)_{x_0}$}.$$
This IVP has a unique solution $u_{x_0}$ for all $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now, consider some set $X$. What can we say about the set of final states of the solutions to $(\star)_{x_0}$ for $x_0\in X$, i.e. the set
$$Y = \{u_{x_0}(1)\colon x_0\in X\}?$$
What properties of $X$ are invariant under $\left(X\to Y, x\mapsto u_{x}(1)\right)$?

E.g., if $X$ is bounded, one can show $Y$ is bounded, too. Or, what about $Y$ if $X$ is a relatively compact $k$-dimensional submanifold? Or...?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think most useful things you can say arise from the fact that the mapping $x_0 \to u_{x_0}(1)$ inherits regularity from $g$. (Note that this already requires the boundedness so that we don't have to worry about finite time blowup.)

Comment: What do you mean by regularity, exactly, @Ian? I think the differentiability theorems yield that $g$ being $C^m$ implies $x_0\mapsto u_{x_0}(1)$ being $C^m$. Is this what you mean? Where could I find some resources on my question?

Comment: One of the first things that springs to mind is that $X$ and $Y$ must be [ambiently isotopic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_isotopy). Or, in the case of smooth manifolds, should they be called *ambiently diffeotopic*?

Comment: @user539887 Perhaps you noticed that we know each other from my similar question on mathoverflow. As you see, I am still working on my question. So, thanks again for your help. Can you direct me to a more detailed discussion of your statement? I know but the classical theorems of ODE theory and I have no idea on how it would follow...

Comment: I have mentioned what just came to my mind. Perhaps there are papers dealing with the problem (or perhaps not?). Maybe in control theory?

Comment: @user539887 Could you please give a brief explanation on how "$X$ and $Y$ are ambiently isotopic." follows? Just a brief rundown of the argument? (I would upvote that as an answer). Yes, my question is motivated by control theory; at the moment I have no hope for relevant papers though... Thanks again!

Comment: In the setup of the Wikipedia entry [Ambient isotopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_isotopy), $F\colon\mathbb{R}^n\times[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined as $F(x,t):=u_x(t)$ and $g\colon X\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and $h\colon Y\to\mathbb{R}^n$ are natural embeddings. If the right-hand side of the ODE is $C^1$ then we can call $F$ a *diffeotopy*, since for each $t\in[0,1]$, $F(\cdot,t)$ is a diffeomorphism (see [diffeotopy](https://planetmath.org/diffeotopy)).

Comment: @user539887 Great, thanks! Do you know where I can find a proof of your last statement? I.e., the statement "... for each $t\in[0,1]$, $F(\cdot,t)$ is a diffeomorphism". Additionally, I think the wikipedia page setup does not allow $X\neq Y$ but you make it sound like one can make it work nonetheless?

Comment: That the mapping $x\mapsto u_x(1)$ is $C^1$ follows from the [Smooth Dependence of ODEs on Initial Conditions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18976/smooth-dependence-of-odes-on-initial-conditions). Its inverse, being the time $-1$ map for $\dot{x}(t)=g(t,x(t))$, $x(1)=x_0$, is $C^1$, too, therefore the original mapping is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Regarding your last question, indeed, in the Wikipedia page one has some outside "model" whose embeddings are distorted in a continuous way. In your case, one can imagine $X$ as some abstract entity $Z$, whose embeddings, as $X$ and as $Y$, change continuously.